# Компиляция скрипта python, использующего tesseract

Tags: python, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Как скомпилировать .ехе скрипта python, который использует tesseract, так, чтобы программа корректно работала на системе где не установлен tesseract? И вобще можно ли это сделать?